# nodes' order changes in node tree

Tags: python, node-editor

If you run a little script like :

```
for node in bpy.data.materials [0].node_tree.nodes:
    print (node.name)
```

You see the order depends on which node is selected and which node you selected before. The current selection is the last in the list. It's true for material nodes, node group nodes and customs nodes tree.

So it's impossible to keep track of a node by is index. Keeping track of a node by it's name is more difficult because the user can change it. So what is the best solution? Maintaining and manage myself a list of nodes added and ordered by it's creation order?

Someone have a suggestion?

Objects in `bpy.data.scene [0].objects` don't change order like that.